# Screen snip sometimes gets stuck in full screen mode

Tags: shortcut-keys, screenshot

I'm referring to the following shortcut in the Keyboard Shortcuts of the settings in Ubuntu 20.04

[image]

Sometimes this shortcut gets stuck on copying the full screen rather than showing a crosshair cursor to select an area. It takes a few tries before it shows me the crosshair. I've tried multiple combinations of the order of my key presses and time held down, and I can't seem to find any pattern.

Note that I have Xmodmap setup to switch my ctrl and alt keys. Not sure if that's related.

Comment: @guiverc thanks for jumping in. `lsb_release -a` gives Description: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, Release: 20.04

Comment: To debug the issue, I would temporarily disable your xmodmap change. If the issue then is not there, you know where to look.