# Screen snip does not work if mouse is still moving on left button release. Is this fixable?

Tags: 20.04, gnome

After almost two years I have finally been able to reproduce [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1302048/screen-snip-sometimes-gets-stuck-in-full-screen-mode) consistently. That is, using the screen snip functionality in Ubuntu (20.04 with Gnome):

[image]

sometimes doesn't save capture area to the clipboard. I realised it happens if you are still moving the mouse when you release the left mouse button. Sometimes this can be annoying as even tiny movements cause the problem. Is there a quick fix for this (hoping this is a common enough problem)? If not, where would I drop this as an issue?

Comment: Can you reproduce the behavior in a 22.04 LiveUSB's "*Try Ubuntu*" environment?

Comment: @user535733 I'd like to find the time to set this up. Can you let me know what I'd expect to get out of the exercise?

Comment: The Gnome screenshot function was changed enormously between 20.04 and 22.04. If the issue is in 22.04, then the bug report that you file is more likely to get attention. If the issue cannot be reproduced in 22.04, then the bug report is more likely to languish.

Comment: @user535733 got it. Thank you.